# Congruent Numbers as the product of hypotenuse and a minor leg of a RRT

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A rational number, $m$, is congruent if it is the area of a right, rational triangle or equivalently if there exists three rationals, $r, s, t$ with $m = t^2 - s^2 = s^2 - r^2$.

I have seen a proof that for any right, rational triangle, $(a, b, c)$, both $bc$ and $ac$ are congruent.

I can prove the converse, that a rational $m$ is congruent only if there exists an RRT, $(a, b, c)$, with $m = ac$ or $m = bc$. The proof is elementary and not too long.

Has this been done? I have not seen any published work on it but don't have access to all of the literature.

Comment: Mainly, I'd like to know if it is worth trying to get this published or not. I'm am amateur mathematician and so I hear that it would be a pain but it it could contribute to the problem then I'm down to try. The proof is entirely at the elementary level

Comment: If the answer is that this isn't interesting, then I'm willing to accept that as well. It's, at best, a minor result.

Comment: Three logicians walk up to a bar. The bartender asks, "do all three of you want a beer?" The first logician says "I don't know." The second logician says "I don't know either." The third logician says "yes." ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its well known even though not often explained.

$x=2 r s$
$y=r^2-s^2$
$z-r^2+s^2$

but if r^2-s^2=#^2 then the squarefree part of x y/2 is r s where r and s are z2 and x2 or z2 and y2

This can be further used to show a whole manner of ways to create congruent numbers from triplets that are not the x y/2 triplet.

$N=x y/2$
$N= y z$
$N= x z$
$N= y^2-x^2$
$N=y^2+z^2$

.
.
.
There are at least 2 more ways.

If you scale a triplet so that x+y-z=2 the triplet generator can be stated in only 1 variable

$x=2+2t$
$y-2+1/t$
$z=2+2t+1/t$

and in this form $n D^2= 3+2t+1/t$